# Oracle Forms ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle11g, tnsnames

I have installed oracle database XE 11g release2, Oracle Weblogic Server 10.3.6, and Forms & Reports 11g.
While trying to connect from Oracle forms to the database, i get the following -
"ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified".
I am connecting successfuly to the database using sqlplus, and tnsping and commandline listener tests are all successful.

My tnsnames.ORA file is in one directory (C:\0_library) and all .env files and user variables are pointing to it.

this is my tnsnames.ORA file:

```
 XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = C3)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
   (DESCRIPTION = 
        (ADDRESS_LIST = 
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = C3)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
        (SERVICE_NAME = PLSExtProc)
    )
    )
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  ) 
ORCL = 
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = C3)(PORT = 1521))
        (CONNECT_DATA = 
            (SERVER = DEDICATED)
            (SERVICE_NAME = orcl1)
        )
    )
```

I know there's alot of similiar questions allready - tried them all and still doesn't work.

Thanks